How to store authentication method in cookie so that log out can be adapted in ASP.NET Core MVC
We're using ASP.NET Core MVC to write a web app. This app requires multiple forms of authentication. At the moment they are username/password and Microsoft Entra. But more might be added going forward.
When logging a user out of the application, we would like to know which authentication method that was used for logging in. If for example Entra was used, we'd like to send the user to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout so that they're properly logged out of the Id provider.
I thought a good idea would be to store an extra claim in the cookie when logging on. I tried to add the following code for that:
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
            {
                options.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
                options.TenantId = "common";
                options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                options.Scope.Add("email");

                options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, "Microsoft");
                    var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
                    await Task.CompletedTask;
                };

            }, openIdConnectScheme: "Microsoft", cookieScheme: null);

The sign in is done using this code in a callback method that is called when user is returned from the provider (in this case Entra):
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

if (info == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
}

// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
   // ..
}

During log out I try to get hold of the authentication method Claim with this code:
var scheme = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod);

// Make some decisions based on scheme....

Unfortunately the scheme is null.
Am I doing something wrong here? Maybe I'm going about this whole thing the wrong way.
Would be grateful for any pointers.

Log the claims on both signin and logout process to get the details. Also to ensure that claim is included, try services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

There's multiple things to check:

On the options variable set SaveTokens = true
If you can't seem to do what you're trying to achieve with built-in
tokens then you can add a custom token here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-8.0#how-to-add-additional-custom-tokens


Not sure about this. Why would saving the tokens help me?
